# Getting the position of an dragged item in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

On dragging an item to a new location I would like to output the new position of the item. for example

Col = 1
Position = 3

meaning the widget has been moved to the first col 3rds down.

I am using this script http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/inettuts/

I think the best place to put this is at the point below. However I tried 
`ui.item.index` to get the new position and this just gives me the value - 1 not the position of the dragged object as excepted. Any ideas?

```
$(settings.columns).sortable({
    items: $sortableItems,
    connectWith: $(settings.columns),
    handle: settings.handleSelector,
    placeholder: 'widget-placeholder',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    revert: 300,
    delay: 100,
    opacity: 0.8,
    containment: 'document',
    start: function (e,ui) {
        $(ui.helper).addClass('dragging');
    },

    stop: function (e,ui) {
        alert("New position: " + ui.item.index());
        $(ui.item).css({width:''}).removeClass('dragging');
        $(settings.columns).sortable('enable');
    }
});
```

Comment: can u post this example to a site like jsfiddle.net so we can see results and ur html markup?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the demo on the nettuts site: [Demo](http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/127_iNETTUTS/demo/index.html)

`ui.item` is already a jQuery object so you can reference it as such.

0-based index position of the **column**:

```
ui.item.parent().parent().children().index(ui.item.parent())
```

0-based index position of the **item**:

```
ui.item.parent().children().index(ui.item);
```

so if you were to drag an item underneath the "Welcome to iNettuts" in the first column the above code would return `0` for column (so the first column) and `1` for the item position (so the second item in the column)

Answer (score 1):

Just to inform you: the script is currently not working on Internet Explorer 9 - the drag functionality fails to work.

I found the following 'workaround':

add

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

to your page.